# Why does the compiler complain when using the abstract modifier in a trait in two cases?

Tags: scala

I am practicing the chapter about trait in the online book Programming In Scala 1ed.

> http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html

There are two examples to show the power of traits, which are enrich thin interface and stackable modification. Here is the snippet of implementation

```
// example 1
trait Relation[T]
{
  def compare(that: T): Int

  def <(that: T) = compare(that) < 0
  def >(that: T) = compare(that) > 0
  def <=(that: T) =  compare(that) <= 0
  def >=(that: T) = compare(that) >= 0
}

// example 2
trait Doubling extends IntQueue
{
  abstract override def put(a: Int) { super.put(a*2) }
}
```

The above code is fine to compile.

I am curious the existence of `abstract` modifier, so first I added the a `abstract` modifier in front of `Relation::compare()` in example 1. Maybe it's reasonable to mark `abstract` to `compare` which is going to be override by subclass.

```
// case 1
abstract def compare(that: T): Int
```

Then compiler complains

```
Error:(19, 16) `abstract' modifier can be used only for classes; it should be omitted for abstract members
abstract def compare(that: T): Int
           ^
```

I think this message says it should not put `abstract` modifier in trait. So I try to remove the `abstract` modifier from Doubling::put in the example 2 just like this

```
// case 2
override def put(a: Int) { super.put(a*2) }
```

But the compiler also complains

```
Error:(35, 36) method put in class IntQueue is accessed from super. It may not be abstract unless it is overridden by a member declared `abstract' and `override'
  override def put(a: Int) { super.put(a*2) }
                               ^
```

I know the reason the `override` modifier here, but I don't know why compiler complains I should add the `abstract` modifier with it. Does the compiler in previous case just complains I should only put abstract in classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say "I think this message says it should not put abstract modifier in trait."  No, it means that in Scala you mark a *class* abstract if it has abstract methods, but don't use the `abstract` keyword on the methods themselves.  The compiler knows that a method is abstract simply because you haven't provided an implementation.

As for the second question, the reason you need the `abstract` keyword on your override of `put` is that `IntQueue`'s `put` is abstract.  You are telling the compiler that `super.put(a*2)` is not really an attempt to call an abstract method, which of course would not work -- you expect a trait to be mixed in which provides the implementation.

More info [here](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html).

Comment: So there is no need to add abstract keyword in front of a abstract method? And this works because of lack of implementation already hint compiler it is a abstract?

Comment: That's right.  The only time you need to use the abstract keyword on a method is in your case #2, where you are overriding an abstract method and calling it via super.  The word "abstract" in that case does not mean "this method is abstract," but rather "I realize that this overrides an abstract method, so a trait implementing the method will have to be mixed in before this trait."